# Consumer-Producer threads with DirectX desktop frames

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, directx, directx-11

I'm writing a DirectX application with two threads:

- Producer thread grabs desktop frames with DirectX (as in the [Desktop Duplication DirectX sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Desktop-Duplication-Sample-da4c696a))

  ```
  IDXGIResource* DesktopResource = nullptr;
  ID3D11Texture2D *m_AcquiredDesktopImage = nullptr;
  HRESULT hr = m_DeskDupl->AcquireNextFrame(500, &FrameInfo, &DesktopResource);
  hr = DesktopResource->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), reinterpret_cast<void **>(&m_AcquiredDesktopImage));
  DesktopResource->Release();
  // The texture pointer I'm interested is m_AcquiredDesktopImage
  ```
- Consumer thread performs image processing operations on the GPU.

To avoid copies I'd like to keep everything on the GPU as much as possible. From [ReleaseFrame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404623(v=vs.85).aspx)'s documentation I kinda get that I should call `ReleaseFrame` on the desktop duplication interface as soon as I'm done processing the frame.

My question: should I copy the `m_AcquiredDesktopImage` texture into another one and call `ReleaseFrame` as soon as the copy is finished and return that new texture to the producer thread for processing or can I just get away with returning the `m_AcquiredDesktopImage` texture pointer to the consumer thread? Is this a *copy* of the framebuffer texture or is it the framebuffer texture and I might generate a data race by returning it?

Which one is the correct way to handle a producer of grabbed frames and a consumer of GPU textures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...should I copy the m_AcquiredDesktopImage texture into another one and call ReleaseFrame as soon as the copy is finished and return that new texture to the producer thread for processing or...

Yes, this is the way. You got your texture, you are finished with it and you release it because the data is no longer valid after the release.

> ...can I just get away with returning the m_AcquiredDesktopImage texture pointer to the consumer thread? Is this a copy of the framebuffer texture or is it the framebuffer texture and I might generate a data race by returning it?

The API keeps updating this texture. You are promised that between successful return from `AcquireNextFrame` and your `ReleaseFrame` call the API does not touch the texture and you are free to use it. If you cannot complete your use between the mentioned calls (which is your case, after all you created a consumer thread to run asynchronously to capture) you copy data and `ReleaseFrame`. Once you released it, the API resumes the updating.

An attempt to use the texture after `ReleaseFrame` will result in concurrent access to the texture, your and the API's further updates.

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN documentation on `ReleaseFrame` is a little convoluted. It specifically states you need to release the current frame before processing the next one, and that the surface state is "invalid" after release, which would indicate it is either not a copy, or not a copy that your process owns (which would yield the same effective result). It also states you should delay the call to `ReleaseFrame` until right before you call `AcquireNextFrame` for performance reasons, which can make for some interesting timing issues, especially with the threading model you're using.

I think you'd be better off making a copy (so `ReleaseFrame` from the previous capture, `AcquireNextFrame`, `CopyResource`). Unless you're using fences you don't have any guarantees the GPU will be consuming the resource before your producer thread has called `ReleaseFrame`, which could give you undefined results. And if you *are* using fences, and the `AcquireNextFrame` call is delayed until the GPU has finished consuming the previous frame's data, you'll introduce stalls and lose a lot of the benefits of the CPU being able to run ahead of the GPU.

I'm curious why you're going with this threading model, when the work is done on the GPU. I suspect it makes life a little more complicated. Although making a copy of the texture would remove a lot of those complications.